# Is it possible to create an error in the input class, or what is the difference between str and input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, input

If I try to place the following value : `"'` as text when by putting it in brackets as follows: `a = str(""'")`, it will give the following error:

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

On the other hand if I enter `"'` as an input it will accept it by default as a string.

How does the input class manage to convert it to string?

And is there any sequence of keys that will cause the input class to get an error when receiving a value and converts it to string?

Comment: In `""'"`, the second double-quote ended the string literal started by the first one, then the single-quote started a new literal that was never ended.  You need to *escape* at least one of the quote marks: `"\"'"` or `'"\''` would produce `"'` as desired.

Comment: @jasonharper what dos the input class do?

Comment: `input()` is a function, not a class - it just accepts whatever is typed, nothing has any assigned meaning, so there is no possibility of a SyntaxError, no matter what you type.  (Well, you can create a KeyboardInterrupt by typing `Control-C`, but that's something your terminal does, `input()` has nothing to do with it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want both quote marks: `"` and `'` inside a literal string, you can either add them separately or you can use so-called triple-quotes to surround them:

```py
a = '''""' '''  # note the trailing space
b = """ ""'"""  # note the leading space
print(a)
print(b)
```

This may not be what you want.

Alternatively:

```py
double = '"'
single = "'"
a = double + single
print(a)
```

Comment: Is that what the input class does triple-quotes?

Comment: No, the `input()` command is handled completely differently internally. It simply passes the keystrokes from the user into a string without knowing what values they are. The problem you are facing is how to get the python code itself to represent the quote marks in the text of the program itself.

Comment: unclear. What method do they do to get string values without getting the error?

Comment: The `input()` function must be connected to an API from the operating system, so it could be that when a key is pressed there is an event and python could execute something like: `ch = event.key.value` and then: `return_string += ch`. There are no quotes of any kind involved in the code.